# How to calculate the Average of Time from a NotesDateTime array in Lotus Script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

How to calculate the Average of Time from a NotesDateTime array in Lotus Script.
I have an array of NotesDatetime values where I want to have an average of the time from the NotesDatetime value. Is there any easy way of doing it. Any code snippet will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Calculate the time difference (seconds) with [TimeDifference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_TIMEDIFFERENCE_METHOD.html) from a
   certain date time value (e.g. Now) to every element of your
   NotesDateTime array.
2. Calculate the average of all time differences.
3. Calculate the average date time value with [AdjustSecond](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ADJUSTSECOND_METHOD.html) adjusting the certain date time value (e.g. Now) to the average of all time differences.

Comment: looks like a good approach. Just make sure your 'certain date time value' is always the same during the complete process.